What's the way to keep data that will never change?
I have some data that will not change. That data is nested menu names for the entry screen of the application.
I attempted to store the data using Android Room, but it seemed unnecessary. Even if it were successful, it would be unnecessary because the data will not change.
Then I tried to store the data using a string resources array. It looked good, but I needed nested arrays, and this option was not suitable for that reason.
So in this scenario, what is the best way to keep this constant data?

A simple solution is just a Kotlin object:
object Whatever {
   val yourOuterMenu = listOf(
     listOf(...),
     listOf(...),
     listOf(...)
   )
   // etc.
}

Alternatively, you could store a JSON or XML file as an asset in src/main/assets/ and read it in using AssetManager. IMHO, this only adds value if either a non-programmer needs to maintain the file or you will generate it using some tool.

Is it good practice to keep these menu names and submenu names as class members? I will need to share its ID with the navigation controller when the submenu is clicked.
I also tried listOf( Pair(MENU,listOf(SUBMENU), ... ), does this approach fit your scenario?

@striver: "Is it good practice to keep these menu names and submenu names as class members?" -- that would depend on a wide variety of considerations that are well beyond the scope of this question. For example, if you intend to support multiple languages, you need to first decide how you want to do that (Android string resources? Kotlin Multiplatform string resources? something else?). Only then can you decide how well the object approach will mesh with your multi-lingual plans. "does this approach fit your scenario?" -- that's fine, I was trying to match your question.

Android studio provides an opportunity for working with XML files. Example of file:
<parent_element>
    <element1>
        <nested_element_1>Some data</nested_element_1>
        <nested_element_2>Some other data</nested_element_2>
    </element1>
    <element2>
        <nested_element_3>Some data</nested_element_3>
        <nested_element_4>Some other data</nested_element_4>
    </element2>
</parent_element>

